# configure php-fpm to work only in one directory and HHVM on the rest

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php

I am trying to test HHVM and php-fpm on the same site, running both. But I want php-fpm to work only on one directory, but I think I am not getting it right

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
# or if you used a unix socket
# fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
}
location /checkout {
fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I get a file not found when getting in to /checkout

Nginx error :

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

It this actually possible to achieve ?

Comment: Post the complete `server` block. And also the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, I had exactly the same question. And solved it, yay!

Just try this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # /checkout/ or /checkout - just try it out
    if ($request_uri = '/checkout') {
        # using php-fpm
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
    # using hhvm
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
}
```

Important: be very specific with the $request_uri

I think your problem was, that you had also in your config:

```
location / {
    try_files some_url /index.php?$args;
}
```

I think (well, I'm new with nginx) nginx does the following:

1. looking for location `/checkout`
2. matching the `location /checkout`-block
3. can't find fastcgi script `/checkout`

   - meaning it never applied `try_files` with the `/index.php?$args` rewrite

Additional thoughts:

For better reliability, I use for the hhvm-route `fastcgi_pass php;` and in the http-block:

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock; # hhvm
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock backup; # php-fpm
}
```

With this config I have a fallback if hhvm crashes.

Also there should be a better way for switching based on $request_uri...